# Support for the curve FRP256v1

Tags: elliptic-curves, openssl

When i list down the curves using `openssl ecpram -list_curves` where in which I didn't see any curve named FRP256v1.
Does openssl actually supports FRP256v1? If so can you please let me know the version in which the support for this curve exists?
The openssl version where in which I checked this is `OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that this curve is supported in the latest version of the code.  The prime for that curve is not present in OpenSSL's list of curves or elsewhere in the source code.

Unless you have a specific need to use this curve, you're probably better off using a more common curve, such as Curve25519 (preferred) or prime256v1 (if you need ECDSA).  Those curves will be implemented in a constant-time manner and usually accelerated with special assembly to be much faster than alternatives.

Comment: Sure, it was needed to support as a part of requirement, I done couple of searches to find the OID for this curve couldn't find it, if you know can you please share me the OID of this curve?

Comment: Here's a link with metadata including the OID: https://neuromancer.sk/std/anssi/FRP256v1.

Comment: Thank you, if there is a way that(online/offline) I can generate self signed cert using FRP256v1 can you please share, or even if you have some sample self signed cert of FRP256v1 can you please share?